# Best way to use bootstrap tabs with their contents

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navigation bar with their contents when clicking. My code looks like lame. Is there a way to shorter my code?

E.g: When Rooms clicked, JQuery adds `active` class to `#nav-hotel`, and removes `active` class from other `li`elements. It also sets `visibility` and `display` of both itself and others.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li id="nav-hotel" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-hotel">Rooms</a></li>
                <li id="nav-flight" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-flight">Flights</a></li>
                <li id="nav-restaurant" role="presentation"><a href="#tab-restaurant">Restaurants</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab-hotel">hotel</div>
                <div id="tab-flight">flight</div>
                <div id="tab-restaurant">restaurant</div>
            </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#nav-hotel").click(function () {
        $("#nav-hotel").toggleClass("active");
        $("#tab-hotel").css("display", "block");
        $("#tab-hotel").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#nav-flight").removeClass("active");
        $("#tab-flight").css("display", "none");
        $("#tab-flight").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#nav-restaurant").removeClass("active");
        $("#tab-restaurant").css("display", "none");
        $("#tab-restaurant").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
    $("#nav-flight").click(function () {
        $("#nav-flight").toggleClass("active");
        $("#tab-flight").css("display", "block");
        $("#tab-flight").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#nav-hotel").removeClass("active");
        $("#tab-hotel").css("display", "none");
        $("#tab-hotel").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#nav-restaurant").removeClass("active");
        $("#tab-restaurant").css("display", "none");
        $("#tab-restaurant").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
    $("#nav-restaurant").click(function () {
        $("#nav-restaurant").toggleClass("active");
        $("#tab-restaurant").css("display", "block");
        $("#tab-restaurant").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#nav-flight").removeClass("active");
        $("#tab-flight").css("display", "none");
        $("#tab-flight").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#nav-hotel").removeClass("active");
        $("#tab-hotel").css("display", "none");
        $("#tab-hotel").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using data-toggle="tab"? I recently created a similar example with no javascript by including bootstrap.min.js, jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.css and marking the tabs.

First, mark your "a" items with data-toggle="tab"

```
 <li id="nav-hotel" role="presentation">
   <a href="#tab-hotel" data-toggle="tab">Rooms</a>
 </li>
```

Second,mark you div content items with class="tab-pane"

```
<div id="tab-hotel" class="tab-pane">hotel</div>
```

Finally, to add a default enabled tab add the active class to one of your divs

```
<div id="tab-hotel" class="tab-pane active">hotel</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know about `data-toggle`. Thank you for your help!